# QuickFIXJ 2.3 - onDisconnect(), onConnect()

Tags: quickfixj

I am using Quickfixj 2.3 for initiator. Vendor party is acceptor .

I have implemented  SessionStateListener with the methods onConnectException and OnDisconnect.

I have resetOnLogon =Y in configuration file .

1. How can I catch specific exception like EndOfStream occurred ,due to wrong session data or due to acceptor allows only one session at a time or due to invalid Msg seq ?
2. Now, when the resetOnLogOn=Y,until the msgSeq satisfies, it keeps internally the disconnecting and initiating. I would like to logout manually in all other disconnects except this situation where it auto matches the seq number .

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

You actually cannot tell the scenarios listed in point 1 apart most of the time.

E.g. the counterparty normally will not tell you if you have wrong session data (I assume you mean wrong `SenderCompID` or `TargetCompID`) because that would disclose information about their system. Same goes for the duplicate session.

Only in the case of a "sequence number too low" event the counterparty normally will send this information in the `58/Text` field of the `Logout` message.

Comment: Ok for point 1.  For point 2, the Logout reason come in fromAdmin method,however, being resetOnLogon , refreshOnLogon, it will keep disconnecting(which triggers internal logout) initiating logon again until the condition matches. So in this scenario,in disconnect I don't want to logout.  Now second scenario, when connection already initiated, then second attempt will make endofstreamencounterd, then I want to logout. But I can't catch this msg in disconnect as method signature is empty.

Comment: I would strongly advise against doing resetOnLogon when the counter party doesn't reset their sequence numbers on logon which will lead to the sequence mismatch you are seeing.

Comment: Moreover I don't know what you mean by "auto matches the sequence number". Either it is too high, then it will be synchronised automatically. Or it is too low, then the connection will be logged out.